# How facebook and google can detect my device

Tags: javascript, php, html

I was wonder how facebook and google redial different links for different devices and also they redial there lite veesion to the android or IOS opera mini too. So i research a little bit and got some idea about detection user agent with java script but I can't find any real answer or code so that I can use it for my website.

So anyone know how its done and get me that code and I also think the php code would be the best if its possible cause user could disable there javascript.

Comment: what you want ?? device detect from website??

Comment: http://mobiledetect.net/ this is a simple library i think this will help you

Comment: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/exploring-javascript-device-apis

Comment: Yea i wana detect there device user agent and redial three different version of my website like destop, mobile and lite version.

Comment: Thanks the Mobiledetect.net website was a great help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PHP:

```
var_dump( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );
```

More at: [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Using Javascript:

```
alert( navigator.userAgent );
```

More at: [W3School.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp)